# ASP.NET - Validating Form Before Standard Validation

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, validation

I have an ASP.NET form where I have an ImageButton control as follows (please note that this only part of a bigger form):

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="checkbox1" Text="Validate" Enabled="false" />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="textbox1" MaxLength="30" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="validator1" ControlToValidate="textbox1" Text="required!" runat="server" ValidationGroup="group1" />
<asp:ImageButton ID="button1" runat="server" Width="24" ValidationGroup="group1" />
```

Using Javascript, I could disable and enable the RequiredFieldValidator as follows:

```
function test() {
  var checkbox1 = document.getElementById("<%=checkbox1.ClientID %>");
  var ckOwnerIsOperator = document.getElementById('<%=ckOwnerIsOperator.ClientID %>');

  if (checkbox1.checked)
    ValidatorEnable(validator1, false);
}
```

What I am looking for is an event that fires before the validation on the button when the button is clicked.  I know I could do this on checkbox click event, but it is not what I need.  The checkbox click event has a problem where I lose the validator state if another control triggered an async postback, so I want the test() function to be called before the page validation occurs.

Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add `onclientclick="test()"` to the button.

Comment: That worked... for some reason I thought I tried that, but apparently not!  Thank you

Comment: Maybe you used `onclick` like I originally had before my edit.  It is pretty easy to confuse the two when coding fast.